Memory accesses during object relocation with ZGC
I understand that ZGC is a GC that can execute concurrently with user threads for most of the time, even object relocation can be done in parallel with user threads. However, I'm curious about how ZGC ensures safety during object relocation.
If a GC thread is currently copying data from region1, but after the copying starts and before it ends, a user thread attempts to modify the data of an object in region1, what will happen? How does ZGC handle such conflicts?

I have tried to read the papers related to ZGC and some parts of the ZGC source code, but I am still quite confused.

I think there is a write barrier inserted which checks for the GC operations (in that area or for that object) on every write access (and wait until the copying is finished).

However, after reading the ZGC memory barrier code, it seems that there is no write barrier code? Since my C++ level is not very good, I really can't understand the source code well, and it's possible that I missed something.
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/gc/z/

According to this paper, this seems to be the case: "ZGC departs significantly from previous GC algorithms in the HotSpot JVM by utilizing load barriers instead of write barriers". Also, it mentions "No access (read/write) to reclaimed memory (objects) occurs during concurrent relocation."

And it seems like section "3.8 Relocation (RE)" of the aforementioned paper suggests that it also uses load barriers for that purpose in some way.

However, in the paper, there is a sentence that says: "Mutators that access an object concurrently with its relocation will hit the slow path of the load barrier, as the pointer’s color will invariably be bad." This seems to suggest that ZGC allows user threads to access objects while the GC is moving them?

I speculate that the meaning of this sentence (No access (read/write) to reclaimed memory (objects) occurs during concurrent relocation.) is that ZGC does not access the contents of the objects when they are being reclaimed, rather than prohibiting user threads from accessing the objects that need to be moved.
